# NEC Wire Size for Neutral Question

Tags: wiring, code

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question. In my shop, I have a solid state phase converter that is creating three phase power for some of my machinery. It's fed by two 150 amp circuits off the main panel wired with 1ga wire. The phase converter feeds a 3Φ sub paneled wired in a delta plus ground (4 wire, 6ga breakered for 60A) configuration. I need to run a neutral to one of the machines for a 120v control. Adding a neutral from the main panel is not a problem. I just need to know what size wire I should use. The machine it's self is on a 30A circuit (10ga wire). Can I us a 10ga neutral back to the main panel, or do I need to match the wire sizes at each branch all the way back including the #1 wire supplying the Phase converter?

It just occurred to me that I can't use a neutral from the panel like that and would need to create a neutral via a delt wye transformer at the machine. Can some confirm this?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions is a better fit for your question ... please delete this question after you post there

Comment: This is an electrical engineering design question though. It may elicit more answers on the DIY forum, but electrical engineering encompasses a lot of civil work. It’s not all about little circuits. Big ones too :) To me, an NEC question is spot-on.

Comment: If you are licensed for such work, this is a good resource.  You better be legit though, https://www.electriciantalk.com/forums/